# Resources on surjunctive groups.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

Are there any free available resources on surjunctive groups which are available to say: a graduate level student?

A textbook would be fine also.

Regards.

Comment: ...initially I thought this was a typo for 'surjective'. Pardon the ignorance of a lowly undergraduate student. If someone doesn't answer, perhaps you could ask on Overflow. You might get more traffic from people knowledgeable on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try Ch.3 of the book "Cellular Automata and Groups" by Ceccherini-Silberstein and Coornaert. I have had to refer to this book for other things and it is fairly leisurely. I am certain you can find this book somewhere (it is even complementary if your institution has a Springer subscription).